# AKPickerView with reloadData results in weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal `AKPickerView` from the library https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView-Swift. The selected item in the `AKPickerView` gets an underline and a bigger font.

My demo shows what I created so far, It's possible to create an underline and a bigger font for the select item .. but my implementation results into  some weird behaviour. The other cells behave strangely after setting an item as seen here:

[image: picker view]

I think it has to do with reloadData and dequeuing cells but I have no idea how to achieve my wanted results, whats causing this error?

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AKPickerView_Swift

class SystemSetupTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: AKPickerView!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitTitle: UILabel!

    fileprivate var answers: [String]!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
    }

    func configure(questionTitle: String, answers: [String]){
        self.questionTitle.text = questionTitle
        self.answers = answers

        pickerView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 50)
        pickerView.highlightedFont = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 100)
        pickerView.reloadData()
    }
}

extension SystemSetupTableViewCell: AKPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfItemsInPickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView) -> Int {
        return answers.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, titleForItem item: Int) -> String {
        return answers[item]
    }
}

extension SystemSetupTableViewCell: AKPickerViewDelegate {

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, configureLabel label: UILabel, forItem item: Int) {

        if pickerView.selectedItem == item {
            let underlineAttribute = [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
            let underlineAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: label.text!, attributes: underlineAttribute)
            label.attributedText = underlineAttributedString
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: AKPickerView, didSelectItem item: Int) {

        pickerView.reloadData()

        unitTitle.text = "\(answers[item]) liters"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by updating the code from the library.

The changes are:

- override `isSelected` from the cell, this way the cell registers changes.

More information can be found on: https://github.com/Akkyie/AKPickerView-Swift/issues/35

SimonArcher has the correct solution.